# Elegant proof of icosohedron property

Tags: group-theory, contest-math, polyhedra, pigeonhole-principle

This problem was question A1 on the 2013 Putnam contest. Is there a better way to solve this problem than just using pigeonhole principle? Specifically, is there a group theoretic way to interpret this problem? The problem goes:

"Recall that a regular icosohedron is a convex polyhedron having 12 vertices and 20 faces; the faces are congruent equilateral triangles. On each face of a regular icoshedron is written a nonnegative integer such that the sum of all 20 integers is 39. Show that there are two faces that share a vertex and have the same integer written on them."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every face touches $3$ vertices, thus every number can appear at most $4$ times (if you don't want vertices with two faces sharing the same number). Now consider the minimal filling of number which would be possible t do this way, using only $0,1,2,3$ and $4$, each of them appearing exactly $4$ times:
$$4\cdot(0+1+2+3+4)=40$$
This implies that at least one of the numbers from $0$ to $3$ must appear at least twice.

Comment: "Every face touches 3 vertices, thus every number can appear at most 4 times." Could you elaborate on this point?

Comment: @AustinMohr Well, if a number was to be present $n>4$ times without two different faces with said number sharing a vertex, then we would need $3n>12$ vertices. Since the icosahedron has only $12$ vertices, this is clearly not possible.